# Why do I see folders of my computer under IP which I don't see in ipconfig?

Tags: windows, ip, nas

At first, I could not connect to my NAS (which has static IP 192.168.1.100) from my notebook. But I can connect to it with all my other PCs. So I suspect some error somewhere in that notebook.

My network configuration is following:

- wifi router with DHCP server enabled, static IP for NAS reserved
- NAS with IP 192.168.1.100 assigned
- problematic notebook connected through WIFI with dynamic IP 192.168.1.106 (right now)
- When I run 'ipconfig /all' I see that notebook has ..1.106 IP assigned (as expected). I don't see any other IP there (as expected).
- I checked every network adapter settings for static IP (on notebook), nothing found.
- There is one VPN adapter on notebook, but currently disconnected

When I input NAS IP into any browser on notebook it returns NOT FOUND message (this is wrong).
BUT when I input **NAS IP** into Windows Explorer it shows me **shared folders of itself**, of current NTB. (**which is very weird**, and I cannot explain this).
Same shared folders I see when I input notebook's IP (which is correct)

How is this possible? How can I get this right (meaning I want to see NAS folders when I input its IP in WinExplorer)? What settings I can check or correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what NTB stands for? Netbook?

Comment: I meant notebook. Sorry, I'll replace that.

Comment: you probably should check hosts file and `route print` output

Comment: I have already checked hosts file and it is clean. I will check 'route print' command this evening. Thanks for the tip!